# Metadata standard for NFT

Tags: smartpy, metadata

Is there any metadata standard for NFT in tezos, there must be some standard in which the tezos market place supports the token contract. Do we have any contract example in mainnet that will help in understanding more about the metadata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the main NFT metadata standard is described in https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-21/tzip-21.md and it relies on https://gitlab.com/tezos/tzip/-/blob/master/proposals/tzip-16/tzip-16.md